# Cognito DynamoDB aws sdk in mobile app

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, ionic-framework, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

```
  AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESSKEYID,
    secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_ACCESSKEYID,
    region: AWS_DYNAMODB_REGION
  });

  var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
```

I'm using the javascript aws sdk in an ionic mobile application, I only use it to do a simple query of my dynamodb instance.  I am using aws access key and aws secret access key id in AWS.config - and not Cognito.  The access key id and secret access key are stored in my app config.

Should I switch to Cognito instead of aws access key and secret?  My app is a mobile app and not a browser app so these values will not be visible to users.  I already have a Cognito identity pool set up, in case I make the switch.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Secret keys cannot be securely stored on a mobile app. It is recommended that you use Amazon Cognito and create scoped roles. If you scope your role to access a dynamodb row per identity id,  the temporary credentials vended by Cognito on a device can access to the specific row belonging to that identity only.

Comment: This should be a good starting point: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-started-with-identity-pools.html